Order of magnitude of damping in a mems accelerometer
If you let fall for example a phone which includes a MEMS accelerometer, the acceleration goes from approx 10 m/s^2 to 0 m/s^2 almost immediately, as described for example in the following graph (from this paper):

However a falling mass spring system should oscillate as for example described here.
Nevertheless one doesn't see such an oscillation in the data, which indicates for me that there must be a reasonable damping in the system.
Now I want to understand this more detail:
What order of magnitude are the relevant parameters in a real mems accelerometer (as used for example in a phone):

proof mass
spring constant
damping and kind of damping

Are there other parameters I need to take into account to explain why one doesn't see an oscillation. How to explain with a suitable calculation that it doesn't occur?

The damping is in the phone/pillow system, not the accelerometer. That latter has a much higher resonant frequency than the phone/pillow system and is operating in the lightly damped baseband region.

@GregLocock; I think you misunderstood my question. My question about why we don't see any oscillation between ~0,6s and 1s.

Nope, i understood it just fine. Source : dynamics test/simulation engineer for 42 years. I suggest you model a 2dof system, accelerometer and iphone/pillow in series, and see how the damping of the accelerometer, with a tiny mass and a high stiffness, affects the measured response.

Not posting as an answer since it doesn't answer all your questions; According to Wikipedia, "Damping results from the residual gas sealed in the device."
